# stop SVG feSpecularLighting filter from filling outside of a <rect> Element

Tags: svg, xhtml, svg-filters

I am developing in Chrome and Firefox and I've been having trouble with an SVG filter. when applied to a rect it seems to affect more than just the `<rect>` element. Below is a screenshot of the result. As you can see it shades outside of the `<rect>` which is undesired.

Below is the result in Chrome:
[image: undesired result in Chrome]

Below is the result in Firefox:
[image: undesired result in FF]

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head></head>
<body>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" baseProfile="full" width="100%" height="100%">
<defs>
<filter id="dropshadow" height="130%">
<feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="10"/> 
<feOffset dx="5" dy="5" result="offsetblur"/>
<feMerge> 
<feMergeNode/>
<feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/> 
</feMerge>

<filter id = "I">
<feSpecularLighting specularExponent="2" lighting-color="#F3F4F3">
<fePointLight x="300" y="100" z="100"/>
</feSpecularLighting>
</filter>
</filter>
</defs>

<rect x="33%" y="33%" rx="30" ry="30" width="33%" height="300px" style="fill:#FFFFFF; filter:url(#I)"></rect>

</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because the default [filter effects region](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html#FilterEffectsRegion), as defined by the `x`, `y`, `width` and `height` parameters on the `<filter>` element, is 120% of the bounding box of the filtered element, not 100%.

The specification clarifies:

> It is often necessary to provide padding space because the filter effect might impact bits slightly outside the tight-fitting bounding box on a given object. For these purposes, it is possible to provide negative percentage values for ‘x’ and ‘y’, and percentages values greater than 100% for ‘width’ and ‘height’. This, for example, is why the defaults for the filter effects region are x="-10%" y="-10%" width="120%" height="120%".

Changing this to 100% would still affect the entire bounding box, though, so including the areas outside the rounded corners of the `<rect>`. If you want to limit it to just the rectangle, you can use [`feComposite`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html#feCompositeElement). E.g.

```
<filter id="I">
    <feSpecularLighting specularExponent="2" lighting-color="#F3F4F3" result="light">
        <fePointLight x="300" y="100" z="100"/>
    </feSpecularLighting>
    <feComposite in="light" in2="SourceAlpha" operator="in" result="lit"/>
</filter>
```

Also, you've nested the `#I` filter inside the `#dropshadow` filter. That's not something you can do. Are you trying to combine the lighting and drop shadow? If so, you could do that like this:

```
<filter id="dropshadow">
    <feSpecularLighting specularExponent="2" lighting-color="#F3F4F3" result="light">
        <fePointLight x="300" y="100" z="100"/>
    </feSpecularLighting>
    <!-- Apply lighting inside rectangle -->
    <feComposite in="light" in2="SourceAlpha" operator="in" result="lit"/>

    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="10"/>
    <feOffset dx="5" dy="5" result="blur"/>
    <!-- Apply blur outside rectangle -->
    <feComposite in="blur" in2="SourceAlpha" operator="out" result="shadow"/>

    <!-- Combine lighting and shadow -->
    <feComposite in="shadow" in2="lit" operator="xor" />
</filter>
```

This doesn't seem to work to work in Firefox, though, but then your original example doesn't work in Firefox for me either.

Comment: thank you! I also specified the filterUnits:<filter id="I" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="33%" y="33%" width="33%" height="300px">

Comment: @mgm8870 I would use the default `objectBoundingBox` filter units instead: `<filter id="I" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">`. That way you won't have to change them when you decide to change the size or position of the `<rect>`.

Comment: This works cross browser, but only if you size the SVG canvas explicitly- otherwise it seems to break in Firefox.